# What happens when we call finish() in onCreate() method?

Tags: java, android, oncreate, activity-finish

What happens when we call the `finish()`method for the activity inside `onCreate()`?
Will the app get time to display the `Activity`, but then rapidly close, or won't it show anything? 
This is just a doubt that I had before reading about some malware services for android that allegedly use this idea... Does it effectively work?

Comment: Why don't you try it...?

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: @Ben Kane 
Don't have a computer in hands to test it, and won't have it soon, but had the doubt so I asked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested and debugged it, the `Activity` starts but is immediately closes once the event is generated.

Comment: Thanks! So your activity opens, show and then is rapidly closed... That was what I wanted to know, my very thanks

Comment: If it helps you, you might mark my answer with the check (as correct) @EduardoBrito

Comment: Sure it starts because with `onCreate()` it is started already. This does not mean that anything is shown. The question should be more specific if `onStart()` and `onResume()` are called and if the behaviour is predictable or unstable due to race conditions.

Answer (score 3):

As MrMins mention it will rapidly close. The lifecycle will skip over some important steps, therefore causing potential issues.

But to answer you question it will run only momentarily.

Here is the android documentation of the lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: Yes. Lifecycle events like OnStart, OnResume, OnPause, and OnStop may be skipped, which may cause code that depends on them be in an invalid state. So the Lifecycle would go from Created do Destroyed state directly.

Answer (score 3):

As [per official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)):

> You can call finish() from within this function, in which case onDestroy() will be immediately called after onCreate(Bundle) without any of the rest of the activity lifecycle (onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), etc) executing.

[Since](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#activity-lifecycle)

> The visible lifetime of an activity happens between a call to onStart() until a corresponding call to onStop().

so the "visible lifetime" is not reached for that case.